# Rails namespace class same as existing active_record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

I'm having a bit trouble with the namespaces in Rails 4.

I have ActiveRecord models `Shop`, `Order`, and `OrderItem`

```
# model/shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base

# model/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items

# model/order_item.rb
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orderable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :order
```

I'm replicating the relationship between `Order` and `OrderItem` in a namespace like this

```
# model/shop/order.rb
class Shop::Order
  attr_accessor :order_items
  def initialize
    self.order_items = []
    self.order_items << Shop::OrderItem.new
  end

# model/shop/order_item.rb
class Shop::OrderItem
  attr_accessor :orderable_type, :orderable_id

  def initialize(params = {})
    if params
      self.orderable_type = params['orderable_type'] if params['orderable_type']
      self.orderable_id = params['orderable_id'] if params['orderable_id']
    end
  end

  def price
    orderable.price
  end

  def orderable
    orderable_type.constantize.find_by(id: orderable_id)
  end

  def to_h
    Hash[
      orderable_type: self.orderable_type,
      orderable_id: self.orderable_id,
      price: self.price
    ]
  end

end
```

So my problem is that when I initialize `Shop::Order.new`, sometimes its `order_items` is an array of `OrderItem`s instead of `Shop::OrderItem`s, and when I test it in the controller, if I type `Shop::OrderItem`, it will return `OrderItem`.

I'm wondering if `Shop::OrderItem` wasn't initialized before `OrderItem` and cause the issue?

Comment: How about we see a little more of `Shop::OrderItem`?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why are you doing this?

Comment: @jvillian added more code. I don't want to use the active_record ones to hold the information, the namespaced ones are there to hold shopping info before checking out, so when checking out, i will transfer the info from namespaced one into active_record ones and save to database

Comment: Instead of using a namespace, why don't you add an `enum status: [:pending, :sold]` attribute to your `Order` model instead? 

That way, you are able to store valuable shopping cart information in the same model, but use this `status` flag to handle order sales, payment etc.

Here is some documentation on [enums](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a namespace collision. Depending on where the code is executing, `Shop` could be the ActiveRecord model that you've defined in `models/shop.rb`, or it could be the module namespace that you've defined under `models/shops/*.rb`. Not only will this cause unpredictable execution, it's also confusing to read.

I recommend using a module namespace other than "Shop". Even calling it "MyShop" would be an improvement. However you'll probably still run into naming collisions between `Shop` and `MyShop::Shop`. You should probably rename the Shop class under the MyShop module to avoid this:

For example:

```
# model/my_shop/my_order.rb
class MyShop::MyOrder
  # ...
end
# model/my_shop/my_order_item.rb
class MyShop::MyOrderItem
  # ...
end
```

Having said all that, I feel like you're setting yourself up for a world of hurt. This problem might be better solved using service objects. Google up "Rails Service Objects" for some really good examples.

Comment: https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services and http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.html are pretty good examples of service objects.

Comment: cool, i will take a look. I ended up just renaming the classes, I was hoping to find a way to resolve this without renaming then, I guess there aren't any solutions so far. thanks